# I installed GRUB on the 500 MB partition that Windows 10 made for its launcher and now I can't run Windows

Tags: boot, grub2, windows, launcher

Before you say anything, yes I'm a noob when it comes to Ubuntu or Linux in general. I used to have a problem where  GRUB wouldn't launch and I could only use Windows 10. Now it's the reverse. When I turn my laptop on, GRUB shows up and I can run Ubuntu without any problems. But when I choose Windows 10 (Launcher) it only starts up GRUB once more. Is there a way around this? I still have Windows on my hard disk, I just can't boot it.

Comment: Please have a look on [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: May be best to see details, you can run from Ubuntu live installer or any working install:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/
If you installed grub to the NTFS partition, you damaged Windows and have to repair it. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootSectorFix Instructions - see section on NTFS partition boot sector recovery
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step